# Http Live Streaming without encoding

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, m3u8, http-live-streaming

I have MPEG-TS H.264 video stream of Live TV Channel, I want to Live Stream it for iPhone but as HLS requires to make segments (e.g.: 10s) segment and send it using M3u8. and for this purpose I am currently using ffmpeg and m3u8-segmenter available on internet. But I do not want to use transcoding using ffmpeg as i have memory + processor limitations on my hardware. Is it possible that i can only make segments of the MPEG-TS video and directly send it to the iPhone.

I have tried many ways but unable to do so. I am using Linux based system.

Please help me, what are the procedures of live streaming to iphone without transcoding the video.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using ffmpeg for in this case? If it's already coming in as MPEG-TS, you should be able to feed it to m3u8-segmenter directly. Can you post the sample code and invocations you're using for ffmpeg and m3u8-segmenter?

Comment: @JeffreyPfau

I am using this format:
<br/>
ffmpeg -i [link]http://localhost:6954/myvideo.ts -f mpegts - (all other parameters for encoding) | ./m3u8-segmenter -i - -d 10 -p outputdir/prefix -m outputdir/output.m3u8 -u [link]http://domain.com/
<br/>
As my video is already in MPEG-TS format, thats why i just want to make slices of that video and send it to my iPhone using m3u8.
I am not sure, how to do this.

Comment: I have also tried this:

./m3u8-segmenter -i (URL to MPEG-TS video) -d 10 -p outputdir/prefix -m outputdir/output.m3u8 -u (domain prefix)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this is to cut out FFmpeg entirely. Although you can coerce FFmpeg to not transcode (by using `-c copy`), since the video is already in MPEG-TS format straight off of the livestream, it's best to use it directly.

Since it looks like the video is coming over HTTP, you can use `curl` to print it to stdout:

`curl http://localhost:6954/myvideo.ts | ./m3u8-segmenter -i - -d 10 -p outputdir/prefix -m outputdir/output.m3u8 -u http://domain.com`

Or if you want to use `wget` instead of `curl`, it's similar

`wget -O - http://localhost:6954/myvideo.ts | ./m3u8-segmenter -i - -d 10 -p outputdir/prefix -m outputdir/output.m3u8 -u http://domain.com`

Either `wget` or `curl` will likely already be installed on your system.

Comment: Great! Nice idea. I will do it. I hope it will solve my problem.
Thanks buddy

Comment: @Jeffery: That is working fine on VLC. But It is not getting played on ipad. It keeps on loading. I tried it on simulator and device as well. Now the file sizes are big. With transcoding the file sizes are between 1-2mb and now they are quite bigger 3-15mb depending on the original video.

Comment: Is there any special format which is understood by iOS devices for HLS. because VLC is playing the format but ios does not.

Comment: @ZainRaza It looks like the MPEG-TS stream may be too high profile or bitrate to play on your device, and you may need to end up transcoding it anyway. For more info, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446134/why-doesnt-my-mpeg-ts-play-on-ios) for more information.